# How to change a filename that's input from keyboard

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to answer a school assignment question that wants me to take whatever filenames are input and check if the file ends in `.old`. If it doesn't to change the name to end with `.old`.

It needs to have a structure like what I have here but I'm getting an error with this and I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
#!/bin/bash

for filename in $(ls $1 | grep -v ".old$")
do
        mv $filename $filename.old
done
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: ***Never*** use `for i in $(ls anything)`, see [**Bash Pitfalls #1**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) (there is a reason that is Pitfall No. 1)

Comment: Please do what the `bash` tag tells you do do before posting a question - copy/paste your script into http://shellcheck.net, fix the issues the tool tells you about, then [edit] your question to show that corrected script instead of the one you currently have if you still have a question so we don't have to consider the impact of those bugs while trying to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $ filename=file.new
 $ if [ "$filename" != "${filename%.old}.old" ]; then echo mv $filename ${filename%.old}.old; else echo $filename - nothing to do; fi
 mv file.new file.new.old
 $ filename=file.old
 $ if [ "$filename" != "${filename%.old}.old" ]; then echo mv $filename ${filename%.old}.old; else echo $filename - nothing to do; fi
 $ file.old - nothing to do
```